# How to change fragmnet of a text in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem with replace text in df. I tried to use df.replace() function but in my case it failed. So here is my example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'col_b':['_world1_', '-world1_', '*world1_']})
df = df.replace(to_replace='world1', value='world2')
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't change anything, I still have world1 in my df

Someone have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Use vectorised [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace) to replace string matches in your text:

```
In [245]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'col_b':['_world1_', '-world1_', '*world1_']})
df['col_b'] = df['col_b'].str.replace('world1', 'world2')
df

Out[245]:
  col_a     col_b
0     A  _world2_
1     B  -world2_
2     C  *world2_
```

Answer (score 1):

The value you want to replace does not exist.

That one works:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a':['A', 'B', 'C'], 'col_b':['_world1_', '-world1_', '*world1_']})
print df
df = df.replace(to_replace='*world1_', value='world2')
print df
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
df.col_b = df.apply(lambda x: x.col_b.replace('world1','world2'), axis = 1)

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
  col_a     col_b
0     A  _world2_
1     B  -world2_
2     C  *world2_
```

There could be many more options, however with the function [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) that you are referring to, it can be used with regex as well

```
In [21]: df.replace('(world1)','world2',regex=True)
Out[21]:
  col_a     col_b
0     A  _world2_
1     B  -world2_
2     C  *world2_
```

Comment: Thank you for this advice, it helped me alot :)